# Finding Attributes using Relational Algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

I have a couple of questions that I'm unsure of. Here goes...

The schema:
**Instructor**(InsID, I_Name,DeptName,Salary)
**Student**(SID,StName,DeptName, Tot_Credit)
**Course**(Course_ID,Course_Title,DeptName, credits)

a. Find the course titles for all 3-credit courses offered by the Science dept.
b. Find the student IDs for all students who studied with the Instructor Johnson

I tried to answer them, but I'll need someone to verify/help me find the correct answer.
a. (Pi)Course_Title(Course|X|((sigma)(credits=3 and DeptName="Science")(Course)))

b. (Pi)SID((sigma)(I_Name="Johnson")(Instructor))

I'm not sure if those are correct, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are sites for letting other people make or grade your homework. This is not one of them. What do you doubt about your answers?

Comment: @reinierpost I'm still new to this and I'm not sure if they are correct.

Comment: I know you're not sure. This site expects you to ask more specific questions than just 'Is this OK?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a is correct but can be shorter.  You have 3 ops, only two are needed.
b is incorrect (but I'm not going to spoonfeed anything more).